# JScript.NET: Enumerating WMI collections

Tags: collections, wmi, jscript, wmi-query, jscript.net

In JScript.NET  the following snippet:

```
wmi.js
------
var wmi  = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\cimv2"),
    col =null, prc=null;
col=wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * From Win32_Process", "WQL", 32);
//col=wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_Process");
var e = new Enumerator(col);
for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()){
  prc = e.item();
  print(prc.CommandLine);
}
```

compiles with:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\jsc.exe /platform:x64 wmi.js
```

and executes, but changing the `WMI` call with:

```
col=wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * From Win32_Process", "WQL", 32);
```

compilation still works, while the execution gives the:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: 
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}' failed due to the following error: 
'No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
```

I don't understand why, since for both 
[InstancesOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393870(v=vs.85).aspx) 
and 
[ExecQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393866(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says:

> If successful, the method returns an SWbemObjectSet

Also, WSH JScript can enumerate both `InstancesOf` collection and `ExecQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, remove the flag for wbemFlagForwardOnly and the ExecQuery returns an object that works as expected.

```
var wmi  = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\cimv2")
   , col =null, prc=null;

col=wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * From Win32_Process");
//col=wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_Process");

var e = new Enumerator(col);
for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()){
  prc = e.item();
  print(prc.CommandLine);
}
```

For the explanation, here's a shot in the dark (I don't work with Jscript.NET every day nor am I an expert).

**from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974547.aspx:**

*"A forward-only enumerator performs much faster than the default enumerator, because WMI doesn't maintain references to objects in the SWbemObjectSet"*

**from the error:**

*"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable."*

It seems that converting collection to enumerator requires a reference to the object being casted.  With wbemFlagForwardOnly flag, there is no reference passed so cast fails.

That is how I read this.  Take it for what it's worth.

An interesting thing I found when researching: there is no error with this enumerator using wscript/cscript versus executing exe from jsc/csc.

Also, it seems VBScript has no problem enumerating with these flags; check out the examples and compare - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525775(v=vs.90).aspx.